# Is English the official language for international flights?

Tags: international-travel, airlines, languages

There are specific languages official for every airline (i.e. United Airlines)?

I think the mostly used is English, but what about for example AeroItalia or Sunrise Airways or Cathay Pacific or Air India or Aeroflot? And other international flights?

Is there a rule in this way?

Note: This is a more general version of: [Are most flights to Japan staffed by hosts with good Japanese?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/4596/are-most-flights-to-japan-staffed-by-hosts-with-good-japanese/4597)

Comment: Whilst not a direct duplicate, this is mostly answered by https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/4596/are-most-flights-to-japan-staffed-by-hosts-with-good-japanese/4597#4597

Comment: While I don't think that you intended this with your question, English *is* the official language of international Air Traffic Control

Comment: English is the primary language of Singapore so Singapore Airlines is perhaps a poor example. Airlines on SIA are mostly in English, some are in all 4 official languages of Singapore.

Comment: Airlines based in Singapore (Scoot & SIA) usually only announces in English.

Comment: @AnishSheela They sometimes announce in Malay.

Comment: @ArunabhBhattacharya Oh! I took flights to India only. Probably in different sectors.

Comment: Please stop adding new airline names. The first few were enough, all later additions do not help the question.

Comment: @Willeke I can list any airline from a foreign country.

Comment: @ArunabhBhattacharya, yes, you could but it does not improve the question and it may make the question worse. You got a friendly warning from a moderator that you had edited the question more than acceptable. The next step is that someone will edit the question and take out most of the added airline names. I see that you have already reduced the number of names.

Comment: To add to @MJeffryes, Cathay Pacific and Air India are from countries/administrative regions where English is an official language.

Comment: This question is locked for now as OP keeps changing the airlines, which may make already given answers lose validity.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes. Announcements are made in the local language (to the airline, departure, or arrival) and English. Sometimes it means multiple languages.

From [Europa.EU site](https://www.easa.europa.eu/en/faq/48610):

> ICAO Doc 10086 recommends that information provided to passengers via safety briefings, announcements and safety demonstrations should be transmitted in the language of the operator and in English to promote appropriate communication with passengers

I've never had a flight where they had no English announcements, even domestic flights in China. I've had flights where announcements where in three (pretty often) and even four (more rare) languages.

Comment: It is not always a given that all local languages of departure, arrival and airline will be used and some flights may only use English.

Comment: You've never had the pleasure of flying domestic Aeroflot!   No english whatsoever.

Comment: @PeterM I had, but we all know that Russia lives in an alternative reality. I flew Aeroflot a very long time ago, so can't say if things changed or not :-D

Comment: @littleadv My flights were also a long time ago, and it was definitely different.

Comment: I’d say carrier’s language always, English very close behind, then departure/destination language if different in many cases, but by far not always, and random extra languages if some staff on board speak it.

Comment: @Jcaron and if the carrier has three official languages of which none is English?

Comment: @phoog: I've been on Swiss Air flights that announced in German, French, Italian and English. No Romansh though :-). It does indeed get a bit tedious.

Comment: @Hilmar I flew Swiss to Tel Aviv once... So Add Hebrew to that, and I think they also had an Arabic-speaking attendant...

Comment: I once flew as the only obvious foreigner on a domestic Japanese flight unlikely to be of interest to tourists (Fukuoka-Komatsu, IIRC). The crew asked if I understood Japanese, and when I said yes, they happily skipped the English announcements.

Comment: All Russian domestic flights I've flew in the last 10 years had English announcements, but you can often sense that the pilots are just doing their duty without caring whether their English message ever reaches any destination.

Comment: I have been on domestic flights in Greece with only Greek announcements. It is not self-evident or necessarily required by regulation or law that announcements are made in English in addition to the local language.

Comment: In 1992 or thereabouts, my buddy and I were the only non-Chinese on a domestic flight in China. Not only did they double all announcements in English, the also served everyone on the plane western style cutlery and no chopsticks which appeared to confuse the heck out of most passengers.

Comment: The Dutch flag carrier KLM seems to use English more than Dutch, although they may do some announcements in Dutch, so it's not invariable that the airline's own language will be used (many people flying KLM will be connecting in the Netherlands between two non-Dutch endpoints).

Comment: @PeterM Maybe you was 'lucky', usually there are english announcements. Even after 2022.

Comment: I just flew Aegean from Athens to Brussels, and the anouncements were only in Greek.